# what is the simple subject in "Here, then, is the crux of the matter"

Tags: grammar, subjects

What is the simple subject in the below sentence ?

Question:

> Here, then, is the crux of the matter.

Comment: What has your research shown you?

Comment: i am only used to know simple subjects in sentence like "Every child needs love and nurturing. "  subject=child

Comment: Some would argue that the subject is _the crux of the matter_; others would argue it is _here_. You’re not likely to get the two groups to agree. It’s definitely neither _then_ nor _is_, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here, then, is the crux of the matter.

If you rephrase it:

> The crux of the matter is here.

*I have omitted "then" as it is irrelevant for the answer to your question.*

Which is syntactically equivalent to:

> The man is here.

Since "the man" is the subject of this sentence, "**the crux of the matter**" is the subject in the above sentence.